# Firebase Read and Write Speed

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, nosql

Suppose I am creating a transaction app.

- How will I store transactions?

  *I know I need to denormalize.*
- Would I save the transaction within a transaction node at the first
  db level? Or would i save the transaction node under each user's node? Or would i save it in both the transaction node on the first level and the
  transaction node under each user's node?
- What if the user changed their name, how would I reflect these
  changes in both the transaction history of the user and the business?

  *I feel like the best way is to put it in just the first level of the database and have the user's query the entire list to see their transaction history.*
- But, If i have a lot of users wouldn't this be extremely slow?

  *Or is firebase smart enough and fast enough to handle such queries.*
- Does the user's internet speed affect this querying, especially on a
  mobile device?
- Can you display the transaction on the screen as it is being loaded?
- Would firebase indexing allow me to do these very large dataset queries easily? Perhaps indexing a user's username that is contained inside each transaction?

Comment: While some of these are valid they are not really appropriate for this site as they are use-case dependent and opinion influenced. Also, there is quite a big of of vagueness; a *transaction*; what does that mean? My definition of transaction and your could be very different. *What if a user changed their name* - that would depend on how their name is stored and how it's being used. Please take a moment and review [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 2):

First, rather than filtering history of transaction data using `username` I would suggest using `userId` which will never changed and always unique.

Second, I think saving the transaction globally (without using `'/userId'`) is better. Because :

1. We need to able to summarize all transactions for accounting reason
2. If you think the query will be slow even after using index, you can consider loading part of query result using `limitToFirst()` just like pagination in web (infinite scroll in android). There is great tutorial [here](https://howtofirebase.com/firebase-data-structures-pagination-96c16ffdb5ca)